# How To Add Image (Image-Path/Binary) to Database with Entity Framework 6 on Asp.Net MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am struggling to add my uploaded image to my database table, in a code first project with MVC 5 and EF 6. Every inputs i.e. Filename, FirstName, Phone no. are updating database but I cannot store image data to store on my database table. (Again to clear the confusion,I am not trying to store image itself.)

I have tried VarChar(Max) as well as VarBinary(Max). I am posting some codes of that specific class in views, controller and model.

This is my model, Movie.cs

```
        public byte[] Poster { get; set; }
        public string AltText { get; set; }
```

My Controller:

```
     [HttpPost]
      [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
      public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = 
      "MovieID,MoviesName,ReYear,Description, 
       UnitPrice,Rating,AltText,GenreID")] Movie movie, HttpPostedFileBase 
            img)
           {

           if (ModelState.IsValid)
              {
               if (movie.img.ContentLength > 0)
                  {
                   string fileName = Path.GetFileName(movie.img.FileName);
                   string extension = 
                      Path.GetExtension(movie.img.FileName);
                     fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString 
                                ("yymmssfff")+ extension;
                     movie.AltText = "~/Content/Poster/" + fileName;
                     fileName = 
                        Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Poster"), 
                         fileName);
                  movie.img.SaveAs(fileName);
                using (MovieContext db = new MovieContext())
                {

                    db.Movies.Add(movie);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.GenreID = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreID", 
                          "GenreType", movie.GenreID);
        return View(movie);
    }
```

And My View:

```
        @model BigHits.Models.Movie
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Movies", null, FormMethod.Post, 
        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

       <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AltText, htmlAttributes: new { @class 
                            = "control-label col-md-2" })
         <div class="col-md-10">
         <input type="file" id="img" name="img"  />
         </div>
       </div>
```

Now I'm Having This error whenever I am trying to upload an image.

```
  Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
   current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
   about the error and where it originated in the code. 

   Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not 
   set to an instance of an object.

  Source Error: 


  Line 92:    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(movie.img.FileName);
  Line 93:    string extension = Path.GetExtension(movie.img.FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AltText, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.'Your attributes', new { @class = "form-control", @type="file" })
```

Comment: It removes my upload field and replaced with text field. This is not what I want.